# Retrieve tracking data using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

I believe I heard recently that it is possible retrieve tracking data using SOAP api and that we can get more data than from data views.

I am familiar with SOAP as such, but after going through Marketing Cloud Api documentation, I can’t even figure out which object is responsible for tracking data. So I am stuck, and I need to get to that data for some GDPR-related data cleanup tasks that we are currently planning.

Could someone point me to the correct documentation, methods and objects?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the help docs: [Retrieve a Tracking Summary of an Email Send Using JobID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/summary_of_send_using_jobid.htm)

Also an example for [sent events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job.htm):

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>SentEvent</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>SendID</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
            <Properties>EventType</Properties>
            <Properties>BatchID</Properties>
            <Properties>ListID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>EventDate</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
               <DateValue>2009-06-30T03:00:00.000Z</DateValue>
               <DateValue>2009-07-29T02:59:59.999Z</DateValue>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Also [Open events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_open_events_details.htm)

Comment: A summary of send does not include subscriber or link level tracking data. It is just email send level summary.

Comment: @MilanSimic Correct, if you look at the two examples I provided Sent & Open you would need to do the same for ClickEvent if you wanted link level information